# Confirming whether a JTextField contains values 0.5-1?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have researched verification of input in a `JTextField` but from what I can see it is only possible to verify whether the input is a `string`, `integer` or `digit`. Could anyone suggest how I could verify the specific value of the digit? For example whether it is in the range `0.5 - 1`. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at [JFormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html), this [site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) helps explain how to use it.

Comment: thanks,this one will help me i hope

Comment: `SpinnerModel model = new SpinnerNumberModel(.5, .5, 1, .01); JSpinner numberRange = new JSpinner(model);`

Answer (score 2):

Two possible ways :

Parse the content of the JTextField to a double variable and use a simple if statement.
You should use a try catch block to handle a possible NumberFormatException (if your text cannot be converted to a double).

Example :

```
double value = 0;
try {
    value = Double.parseDouble (yourTextField.getText ());
}
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // Handle exception ...
}
if (value >= 0.5 && value <= 1) {
    // ...
}
else {
    // ...
}
```

You could also check whether your text matches a given (smart) regular expression.

Consider the following pattern (you need two backslashes to escape a dot and other special characters) : (1(\.0*)?|0?\.[5-9][0-9]*)

This pattern accepts 1 (or 1 followed by decimal separator and any number of zeros occurrences) or a number between 0.5 (this regex allows ".5") and 0.99999...

Example (using [java.util.regex.Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)) :

```
System.out.println (Pattern.matches ("(1(\\.0*)?|0?\\.[5-9][0-9]*)", "0.4")); // -> false
System.out.println (Pattern.matches ("(1(\\.0*)?|0?\\.[5-9][0-9]*)", "0..5")); // -> false
System.out.println (Pattern.matches ("(1(\\.0*)?|0?\\.[5-9][0-9]*)", "0.111")); // -> false
System.out.println (Pattern.matches ("(1(\\.0*)?|0?\\.[5-9][0-9]*)", "0.5")); // -> true
System.out.println (Pattern.matches ("(1(\\.0*)?|0?\\.[5-9][0-9]*)", "0.5000543")); // -> true
System.out.println (Pattern.matches ("(1(\\.0*)?|0?\\.[5-9][0-9]*)", "0.50+")); // -> false
System.out.println (Pattern.matches ("(1(\\.0*)?|0?\\.[5-9][0-9]*)", "1.0")); // -> true
System.out.println (Pattern.matches ("(1(\\.0*)?|0?\\.[5-9][0-9]*)", "1.0000")); // -> true
System.out.println (Pattern.matches ("(1(\\.0*)?|0?\\.[5-9][0-9]*)", "1")); // -> true
System.out.println (Pattern.matches ("(1(\\.0*)?|0?\\.[5-9][0-9]*)", "21")); // -> false
System.out.println (Pattern.matches ("(1(\\.0*)?|0?\\.[5-9][0-9]*)", ".56256")); // -> true
System.out.println (Pattern.matches ("(1(\\.0*)?|0?\\.[5-9][0-9]*)", ".46256")); // -> false
```

Comment: @Mapet I'm glad to hear it. Please consider accepting my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to parse your value of the Textfield to a float like this

```
    float tfValue  = Float.parseFloat(jTextField1.getText());
```

Then you can check if modulo 1 equals 0. If this is true, the value is an Integer.

```
    if (tfValue % 1 == 0) {
        System.out.println("is an integer");
    }
    else System.out.println("is a float");
```

Comment: If the `String` returned from the `JTextField.getText()` contains anything other than numerical digits, parsing would return a `NumberFormatException`. If you were to approach this method, you would need to use a RegEx prior to parsing.

Answer (score 0):

try this, maybe it's help for you

```
                JTextField field = new JTextField();
                field.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {

                    public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                        String text = ((JTextField)evt.getSource()).getText();
                        if (!(evt.getKeyChar() >= '0' && evt.getKeyChar() <= '9')) {
                            // it is number
                        }
                        else if (!(evt.getKeyChar() >= 'a' && evt.getKeyChar() <= 'Z')) {
                            // it is char a-Z
                        }
                        else  {
                            // it others
                        }
                    }
                });
```

but the best way for numbers is use `JFormattedTextField` with specifed mask

Comment: Generally, you don't listen to raw key/mouse events on text components but to the underlying Document.

Comment: @Abihabi 87 i need specifically to have some sort of validation that user made input between 0.5 and 1 if that is not the case then do not let him go further